# Printing a list of numbers from a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, cin

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for integers and places them in a vector until the integer given by the user is 0. Then it should print the integers in the vector.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template <typename A>

void print_numbers(const vector<A> &V){
    cout << "The numbers in the vector are: " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < V.size(); i++)
        cout << V[i] << " ";
}

int main() {

    vector<int> numbers;
    int input;

    cout << "Please type your numbers" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    while ((cin >> input) && input != 0)
        numbers.push_back(input);

    print_numbers(numbers);


    return 0;
}
```

It prints everything except the first integer. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the stray `cin >> input;`. The first number never even makes it into the `vector`. It's consumed before the program reaches the `while` loop.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first input is not stored into the numbers vector. You have

```
cin >> input;
```

and then directly afterward

```
while ((cin >> input) && input != 0)
   numbers.push_back(input);
```

This means that you stored the first number into input, but then wrote over it directly afterwards by doing cin >> input in the while loop without calling the push_back function on the first input.